# FBSDKLoginKit Swift2

Tags: facebook, swift2

I'm developing an App with Xcode7.0 and Swift2.0.

I would like to include Facebook login on my app and i followed different tutorial without any success.

Let me explain :

Here is my [Bridge.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joRfT.png)

I've linked my .framework (as you can see on the left of the screenshot).

The problem is, when i try to set the FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate or even declare a FBSDKLoginButton inside my LoginViewController.

Here is my [LoginViewController.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g64k0.png)

I know my bridge works since i can use Google and KeychainWrapper.h.
I can also declare a FBSDKLoginButton in my Main.storyboad and it opens Facebook without any problems.

It seems the problems is related to FBSDKLoginKit and I can't find any reasons why it's not working. (I'm using the last SDK for iOS)

For example : FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() is working in my LoginViewController.swift and all the requirement in AppDelegate.swift works

That's why i came here to find help. I didn't find anything close or related to my problem yet.

Any help will be appreciate. Thank you

Comment: So the problem doesn't  appear when i compile on my iPhone and appear when i try to compile on Simulator.

Comment: Tried Project Clean? Have you checked the libraries are there in your "Linked Frameworks and Libraries"?